# Clicking too fast on burger menu reverses fadeToggle effect

Tags: jquery, click, reverse, effect

I have a simple problem.
When I click on my Burger Menu,

[Burger Menu before click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xhFg.png)

I want that the background is getting class ".navbar-bg". And the arrow ".navbar-mobile-any-triangle-up" is appearing. Like here:

[Burger Menu after click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZHaQ.png)

On the first view it works super, but when I do some double-click or clicking too fast, it reverses the Burger Menu effect, the background and the arrow. When I double click again, its right again.
Look here:

[Burger Menu after clicking too fast 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYtsP.png)

[Burger Menu after clicking too fast 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQAZ8.png)

How can I prevent that the fast clicking and double click destroys my function?

```
$('.navbar-toggler').click(function() {
    $('.navbar').find('.navbar-mobile-any-triangle-up').fadeToggle(200);
    $('.navbar-bg').fadeToggle(200);
});
```

Comment: Is that jQuery? You need to tag the language used.

Comment: Did it :) Thanks.

Comment: Has nobody an answer? :( I thought this is a general problem and tried to use something like e.preventDefault or stopPorpagation, so that funtion is waiting until animation has ended or sth...